# Extract outline from MATLAB Isosurface

Tags: matlab

I have an isosurface I've plotted in MATLAB, e.g.:

[image: MATLAB Isosurface]

And I'd like to extract the outline from this, for the given view settings that I currently have. The output I expect is like this (produced by GIMP):

[image: Isosurface Outline]

Is there any way to programatically do this so I don't have to manually do it in GIMP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this good enough? Edge detection taken from the [`bwboundaries`](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mathworks.com.au%2Fhelp%2Fimages%2Fref%2Fbwboundaries.html&ei=wJpNVMbjM9K78gWhoIL4BA&usg=AFQjCNF2ulMUUPaYmqbvxKJzhcyjLW01Sw&bvm=bv.77880786,d.dGc) documentation.

```
clear, close all
[x y z v] = flow;
figure(1)
p = patch(isosurface(x, y, z, v, -3));
set(p, 'FaceColor', 'red', 'EdgeColor', 'none');
daspect([1 1 1])
view(3)
grid off
axis off
print -dbmp test

I=imread('test.bmp');
G = im2bw(I, graythresh(I));
[B,L] = bwboundaries(~G,'noholes');

for k = 1:length(B)
    boundary = B{k};
    plot(boundary(:,2), -boundary(:,1), 'k', 'LineWidth', 2)
    hold on
end
hold off
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: That's really nice, except it will only work for one view angle at a time - I'd need to rerun the save image process for panning around the 3d image.

Comment: You would. If you could automate the panning, you could easily automate the rest of the process too. If you're just dragging with the mouse it won't work, but I can think of nothing that would help you do that, except for some kind of callback function that executes when you release the mouse button maybe.